# Updating email addresses in MySQL (regexp?)

Tags: sql, mysql, regex

Is there a way to update every email address in MySQL with regexp? What I want to do is to change something@domain.xx addresses to something@domain.yy. Is it possible to do with SQL or should I do it with PHP for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can search for a `REGEXP` with `MySQL`, but, unfortunately, it cannot return the matched part.

It's possible to do it with `SQL` as follows:

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     email = REPLACE(email, '@domain.xx', '@domain.yy')
WHERE   email REGEXP '@domain.xx$'
```

You can omit the `WHERE` clause, but it could lead to unexpected results (like `@example.xxx.com` will be replaced with `@example.yyx.com`), so it's better to leave it.

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET email = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(email, 1, locate('@',email)), 'domain.yy')
WHERE email REGEXP '@domain.xx$';
```

Answer (score 2):

I would rather do it with PHP, if possible. Mysql unfortunately does not allow capturing matching parts in regular expressions. Or even better: you can combine the two like this, for example:

```
$emails = fetchAllDistinctEmailsIntoAnArray();
# Make the array int-indexed:
$emails = array_values($emails);
# convert the mails
$replacedEmails = preg_replace('/xx$/', 'yy', $emails);
# create a new query
$cases = array();
foreach ($emails as $key => $email) {
    # Don't forget to use mysql_escape_string or similar!
    $cases[] = "WHEN '" . escapeValue($email) .
               "' THEN '" . escappeValue(replacedEmails[$key]) . "'";
}
issueQuery(
    "UPDATE `YourTable`
    SET `emailColumn` =
        CASE `emailColumn`" .
            implode(',', $cases) .
        " END CASE");
```

Note that this solution will take quite some time and you may run out of memory or hit execution limits if you have many entries in your database. You might want to look into [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) and [`ini_set()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) for changing the memory limit for this script.

Disclaimer: Script not tested! Do not use without understanding/testing the code (might mess up your db).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't check it, since don't have mysql installed, but seems it could help you

```
update table_name 
set table_name.email = substr(table_name.email, 0, position("@" in table_name.email) + 1) 
                       + "new_domain";
```

PS. Regexp won't help you for update, since it only can help you to locate specific entrance of substring in string ot check whenever string is matches the pattern. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_position) you can find reference to relevant functions.